# I have an 'if' statement for checking null pointer exception but that line itself is giving a null pointer excpetion

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, nullpointerexception

**Code**

```
if (dataSnapshot.child("Email").getValue().toString()==null) {
                    Email.setText("Email not found");
                } else {
                    Email.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Email").getValue().toString());
                }

                if (dataSnapshot.child("Quote").getValue().toString()!=null) {
                    Email.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Quote").getValue().toString());
                } else {
                    Email.setText("Quote not found");
                }
```

The line of the `if` statement is itself showing an error. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: May be your dataSnapshot is null or dataSnapshot.child("Email").getValue() returning null value.

Comment: It's not funny. You are not considering all the possible situations. Read above comment.

Comment: can you post your `LogCat` where you are getting the exception? because in your `if` statement there are various parts where can throw `nullPointerExceprion`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can rewrite it:

```
if(dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.hasChild("Email") && dataSnapshot.child("Email").getValue() != null ){
    //Your code...
}
```

You have to check for all possibilities.

Comment: Can you add your dataSnapshot value in the question

Answer (score 2):

You're checking if the `toString()` value is null. Only that value.

You're not checking any of the values that precedes it.

`dataSnapshot` could be null.
`dataSnapshot.child("Email")` could be null.
`dataSnapshot.child("Email").getValue()` could be null.

Take each value, save it to a variable, and do a null check on ALL those values.

This is the only way to do it in Java.

Comment: No i checked... its not

Comment: I call bullshit. 100% sure.
Post the actual exception if you have a crash. Otherwise you'll have us guessing forever without getting any help.

Comment: And as you just accepted an answer that states exactly what i said, my 'bullshit calling' was correct.

Comment: It was just the logic man... i mean i had myself told that the database was null

Answer (score 0):

```
if (dataSnapshot.child("Email").getValue().toString()==null) {

}
```

install a breakpoint before if and debug it. I think either `dataSnapshot` is null or `dataSnapshot.child("Email")` is resulting null which is causing err.

Comment: i did... its the value which is null in database